# Joining audio file and all frame picture to video format with Python ffmpeg

Tags: python, audio, video, ffmpeg, steganography

i have a tmp directory which contains a collection of image frames and audio files. i am using linux mint 19.3 and python3.8. in the terminal I type
`ffmpeg -i tmp/%d.png -vcodec png tmp/output.mov -y`
and `ffmpeg -i tmp/output.mov -i tmp/audio.mp3 -codec copy output.mov -y`
then the collection of images and audio in the directory will become a complete video. that I asked

1. when I run it in python using the syntax
   `call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "tmp/%d.png" , "-vcodec", "png", "tmp/output.mov", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)`
   and
   `call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "tmp/output.mov", "-i", "tmp/audio.mp3", "-codec", "copy", "output.mov", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)`
   it does not merge into a video (without output error)
2. I tried the syntax
   `os.system("ffmpeg -i tmp/%d.png -vcodec png tmp/output.mov -y")`
   and
   `os.system("ffmpeg -i tmp/output.mov -i tmp/audio.mp3 -codec copy output.mov -y")`, the video failed to merge with the error output **tmp/output.mov: No such file or directory**

Please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

## Use the full path

Instead of `tmp/output.mov` use `/tmp/output.mov`. Do this for the rest of the inputs and outputs.

## Do everything in one command

```
ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/%d.png -i /tmp/audio.mp3 -codec copy -shortest output.mov
```

Comment: i'm using all your answer not work. ```os.system("ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/%d.png -i /tmp/audio.mp3 -codec copy -shortest output.mov")``` output error ***/tmp/%d.png: No such file or directory***

Comment: @muh.widad Check that the paths to the input and output are correct.